# Open Source document management system

Tags: windows, open-source, document-management

I am searching for an open source document management system to:

- Add my GIS (Geographic information System) documents.
  (All kinds of files: .shp ,.mdb, Word, PowerPoint, Excel, .gdb, .tiff, .bmp, .dwg)
- Store them on cloud storage (I don't have my own server).
- No space limit or document number limit.
- Backup and restore my documents.
- Document workflows.
- Email notification for each change.
- Version control.
- Operate on Windows 7 and 8.
- I don't need sharing and authorization options

I found OpenKM, Dokmee, Zoho Docs, LogicalDOC, NOOMAC Document File Manager, EisenVault, and Doccept but these are all not free.

Where can I find a free open source one?

Comment: As you may have seen (check the edit history) we keep editing your question text. From now on, please write better questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimalist Document Management System](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/minimalist-document-management-system)

Comment: What about using [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive)?

Answer (score 2):

I found [Kimios DMS](http://www.kimios.com/) and [SeedDMS](http://www.seeddms.org/) winch is continuation of a project known as LetoDMS. the Kimios DMS is written in Java so you'll need to run it on Tomcat, Jboss or a compatible application server that can run jsp. SeedDMS is a Php app. both of these will run on windows that being said most of the software of this kind is web based these days.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, **open-source document management system** has become a necessity for every organization to manage its documents with utmost efficiency. Using an open source [document management software](https://www.paperlez.com/), you can keep your organization’s documents digitally. An efficient DMS acts as an organized electronic filing cabinet.

**Benefits of having an open source DMS in your business:**

- Supports multiple file types
- Created for both the individual user and departmental purposes
- Automated document review process
- Efficient push notification feature
- Controllable access control for each individual file
- Meeting Management
- Advanced searching option by category, department, user or by scanning the entire document
- Locating files is quick and easy

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the question. What is your recommendation to use?

Comment: Welcome Aarathi.  Your post is a bit confusing.  What software are you specifically recommending?  Are you recommending Paperlez, to which you embedded a link?  If so, is it open source?  Please make your recommendation clear.  Also, if you have any affiliation with Paperlez whatsoever, please include that information clearly in your answer.  Thank you, and again, welcome.

Comment: Not sure whether this is spam or simply not an answer.